# Excel CONCAT columns B and C while they have similar values at column A

Tags: excel

How can I CONCAT two columns values while the column **A** has similar values in each rows in Excel?

Something like following, what I need is to CONCAT values of rows in Columns **B** and **C** while the **A** is similar:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on Excel 365 and have use of FILTER() and TEXTJOIN(), you can enter the following formula into column D and drag down:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,FILTER($B$1:$C$15,$A$1:$A$15=A1)),"")
```

This checks if the value in column A is the first occurrence of that value.  If it is, it will output a colon delimited string of every value in columns B:C where col A equals the current value in column A.

Answer (score 0):

you can use if command

if cellA1<>cellA2 then you concatenate b2 and C2
else you concatenate D2 and B2, and C2.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper column to do this but you need to have a header row for this to work.  Assuming your first row of data is in A2, B2, C2:

1. paste this into D2:

   `=IF(A2=A1,D1&","""&B2&""":"""&C2&"""",""""&B2&""":"""&C2&"""")`
2. and paste this into E2:

   `=IF(A2=A3,"",D2)`
3. Copy these two down to every row in the data.

Note: This version puts the concatenated result in D at the last row of the group instead of at the first row of the group like your screenshot shows.